# Set basic url to external javascript file

Tags: javascript, base-url

I am not familiar with jquery and javascript, I was wondering how to set the base url of my site in an external js file.

This is the example code:

```
"use strict";
function savelike(post_id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "main/savelikes",
    data: "post_id=" + post_id,
    success: function(response) {
      $("#like_" + post_id).html(response + "");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Didn't understand the question; what should happen when?

Comment: How can I set the website url address here "url: "main/savelikes""?

Comment: Is this what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: No, I need to set the site url to an external js file. I only need it because otherwise the path for the function in the controller will not work.

Comment: Setting URL to external file will open it... you don't want the user to read your JS file, not intentionally. Do you mean you want to import some external JS file?